# Solving a System of Equations syntax confusion

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I have a system of two equations which I would like to solve in terms of a third unknown variable $s$.

```
PP[s_, x_, y_] := (x + s y) (1 - (x + y)/100) 
QQ[x_]         := x
Solve[{PP == x, QQ == y}, {x, y, s}]
```

So I should get an equillibrium (x(s),y(s)) after solving the system. I've done this on paper for x = 0 and x>0, but I want to do this on Mathematica. However with my code I get the following error:

```
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With two equations you can hardly `Solve` for three variables. If you want `x` and `y` to be a function of `s` don't write `s` as a variable to be solved:

```
PP[s_, x_, y_] := (x + s y) (1 - (x + y)/100)
QQ[x_] := x
Solve[{PP[s, x, y] == x, QQ[x] == y}, {x, y}]

(*{{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> (50 s)/(1 + s), y -> (50 s)/(1 + s)}}*)
```

Comment: oh. of course. Thank you.